# array.forEach should return undefined, but it returns array-element, why?

Tags: javascript

The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once for each array element. However, **Mozilla MDN** says that the return value is `"undefined"`? How come?

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});

// expected output: "a"
// expected output: "b"
// expected output: "c"
```

Comment: which one do you mean?

Comment: @NinaScholz So, if I just run the array method without array attached to it I'll get undefined. But if I run array.every, that will give me a boolean value if I run it without an array attached to it?

Comment: You are console.loging which is executing code not returning

Answer (score 2):

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var result=array1.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});

console.log(result)
```

What it says is true the value returned by the forEach(); Is undefined the above piece of code will make you understand

[image]

Comment: Hm, interesting, but I thought that the array.element is what is returned? Hmm

Comment: well, when I started I was like you and obviously everyone is but you have to read more and practice coding every day with you will catch up. Try to read books as much as possible as they cover broader aspects of programming concepts.Don't worry keep coding you'll find lots of errors but all those errors will give you a good lesson

Comment: Any books you can recommend? :)

Comment: http://www.allitebooks.com/ 
visit this site there are plenty of books stat leaning the books from O'Reilly media and manning publications are very nice just grab one that fits for you better.

Answer (score 0):

The callback for [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not need to returns something, because the method is not supposed to return something, compared to [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), which needs a return value for returning a meaningful value.

A callback has only something to do with the element, but not necessarily to return a value to the calling function.

From [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> `forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element; unlike [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) or [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) it always returns the value [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.